# n-ary tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

What is the best way to store n-ary tree (ex: directory hierarchy) in JavaScript ?

I need to have following operations on it:
1. add
2. delete
3 update

Is there any JavaScript library which provide this feature ?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: I would create a class for each type of storage container and store them all inside of another object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a dictionary implementation in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594850/is-there-a-dictionary-implementation-in-javascript) or [Javascript dictionary performance question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4564160/1048572)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is not useful or if I got ur question completely wrong

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript objects are fundamentally maps of key/value pairs, which means you can use them directly for this if I understand you correctly.

For instance, suppose you store words in the tree where each level is keyed by the letter in that position of the word:

```
function storeWord(t, word) {
    var index, ch, entry;

    for (index = 0; index < word.length; ++index) {
        ch = word.charAt(index);
        entry = t[ch];
        if (!entry) {
            t[ch] = entry = {};
        }
        t = entry;
    }
    t.terminal = true;
}

var tree = {};
storeWord(tree, "test");
storeWord(tree, "testing");
// Results in tree looking like this:
// tree = {
//     t: {
//         e: {
//             s: {
//                 t: {
//                     terminal: true,
//                     i: {
//                         n: {
//                             g: {
//                                 terminal: true
//                             }
//                         }
//                     }
//                 }
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }
```

Depending on your needs, your entries may be more complex than just being the next level of the tree.

The above shows the basics of storing, which covers both "add" and "update".

For delete operations, again it depends on how your data is organized, but to *remove* a property from an objcct, you use the `delete` keyword. At its simplest:

```
var foo = {};   // A blank object
foo.bar = 42;   // Now it has a property called bar
delete foo.bar; // Now it doesn't, we've _removed_ the property entirely
```

So when removing a word, you'd find whether it was represented by a terminal in the tree and, if so, remove the terminal and any nodes leading up to it that had become empty.

To tell whether a node is empty, you can use a function like this:

```
function emptyNode(node) {
    var name;
    for (name in node) {
        if (node.hasOwnProperty(name)) { // This is optional if you're using raw objects
            return false; // Not empty
        }
    }
    return true; // Empty
}
```

Using the above, you can build a `deleteWord` function.

Comment: I can think of 2 possible reasons although neither seems to be fair in my opinion. 1. Spite from your discussion with Eswar :) 2. Your answer only briefly covers how an object can be used as a tree structure. You may want to expand it out a bit to include deletes at the very least.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Ooh, good point, I didn't directly address the OP's three operations.

Answer (score -3):

Best way is to store data in directory heirarchy is using Json(JavaScript Object Notation). use JsonEditor class to do CRUD operations.

checkout: http://www.thomasfrank.se/json_editor.html

Comment: They're not JSON objects. They're just objects. JSON is a *textual* data interchange notation.

Comment: The edit is still talking about JSON. JSON has absolutely nothing to do with it except as one possible serialization format for the end result (one amongst many).

Comment: " JSON has absolutely nothing to do with it " .. what is it here? question? I am not editing again because - JS objects are a solution to the OP, I think Json is good to represent tree hierarchy.

Comment: You're thinking of JavaScript [object initializers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). [JSON](http://json.org) is something else entirely (specifically: a subset of initializer syntax optimized for quick parsing, for data exchange).

Comment: Yes! JSON is a subset of JavaScript object initializer syntax(I dint talk about it here), The library i mentioned is used to parse JSON, So i said that his trees can be represented in JSON, and can be operated on using the library i gave in the answer. That,I think, is enough to to answer the question here. I answered for the OP in the current context, Please let me know, why my answer cannot be accepted for the question asked. I really want to know what i am doing wrong!

Comment: I won't bang on about it, but the point is that *in memory*, when you're interacting with it in code (which is what the OP seemed to want), you're not using JSON at all. You're using objects. You might serialize those in JSON, or XML, or plain text, or (frequently, but not in the OP's case I suspect) not at all. It's the difference between a config file, and the in-memory copy of config settings. It's the difference between what a Word file is on disk (might be RTF, DOC, DOCX, whatever) and what Word interacts with when it's open for editing. :-)

Comment: Absolutely, i accept every bit of ur comment , but its not specific to what the OP asked(I think).  But my answer is very specific to the library I had to answer with. Ex: I can't ask him to use XML , while asking him to use the library written to operate on JSON right? Talking about memory.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain why you downvoted? (only if you know what you are doing !)

Comment: Because you suggest horribly convoluted idea - manipulating on stringified serialization, instead of using language's native facilities, which are perfect fit for his particular case.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not useful. Dint the OP ask for a library to do CRUD? Is that wrong ?