# How to traverse the DOM to determine maximum nesting depth?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example:

```
// ...
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
// ...
```

This nest depth would be 3?  But more generally, how can I traverse the DOM to find this information?

I'm interested in treating the DOM like an n-ary tree modeled as an object literal as described in this post:

[n-ary tree in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173254/n-ary-tree-in-javascript)

Comment: Since you don't search for something specific or apply any algorithm to a part of the tree, what's wrong with a simple in-order [full] tree traversal?

Comment: that's fine, how would I implement that best?

Comment: Recursively is the simplest. Just try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only goal is to determine the max nesting level, I'd consider using `querySelector` (since it should be well-optimized):

```
function getMaxNestLevel() {
    var i = 1, sel = '* > *'; /* html > body is always present */
    while(document.querySelector(sel)) {
        sel += ' > *';
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BBtYg/) (with the part of this SO page markup)

Comment: I would bet that this is much slower than some form of DOM walking. Only testing would tell of course.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, you are right, it gets slower (comparing to joellustigman's solution) if the DOM becomes very big, with nesting level over 30 (http://jsfiddle.net/BBtYg/3/). But for relatively flat DOMs, with nesting levels about 20, it seems a bit faster in Firefox and IE11 (http://jsfiddle.net/BBtYg/2/).

Comment: @Crazy - I nominate you to write the jsperf!

Answer (score 9):

**An elegant recursive solution**

use this function as in  - `height(document.body)`

```
function height(el) {
    if (!el.children)
        return 0;
    var max = -1;
    for ( var i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
        var h = height(el.children[i]);
        if (h > max) {
            max = h;
        }
    }
    return max + 1;
}
```

Comment: `el.children` is never falsy thus `if (!el.children)` can be removed

Answer (score 5):

```
function getMaximumDepth (element) {
    var child = element.firstChild;
    var childrenDepth = [];

    if ( ! child ) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (child) {
        childrenDepth.push( getMaximumDepth(child) );
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    return Math.max.apply(Math, childrenDepth) + 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/53R2p/

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is to use a stack. You keep pushing tags until you reach a corresponding/symmetric end tag. Then you can pop or do whatever analysis you'd like to. This is a classic example from a Comp Sci Data Structures class.

Comment: Adding to that... Keep pushing/popping and keep the max stack size you've ever reached in a variable. After the last pop you have the depth. +1 to the answer.

Comment: It's the DOM, not HTML markup. You don't need a stack for "matching tags".

Comment: You're right, Bergi. I am looking at it from a different perspective.

Comment: That is true, but for compute the height of an n-ary tree, recursion is simpler than iteration. As an aside, why is it that n-ary trees grow downwards, but have height rather than depth? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Wouldn't iteration with a stack be shorter? Because you're only collecting/storing half the data, as opposed to recursion where you are storing twice the data (beginning and end tag).

Comment: You're walking the DOM. It's already been parsed into a tree. Like most recursive solutions, there's a simple/special case that usually terminates the recursion and the general case. The simple case is a tree containing no subtrees: it's height is 1. The general (and recursive case) is a tree containing 1 or more subtrees: its height is 1 + the maximum depth of its subtrees (obtained by recursively computing the height of each such subtree and tracking its maximum value). See @MoazzamKhan's excellent answer for an implementation.